# onChange Trigger on Specific Cell Value Change - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange

I have a spreadsheet and have some data in it.

Here I want to trigger a function on Cell **Script!A2 value change.**

I will not change it's value directly.

It will be dependent **by it's formula on below conditions**

**1.** On the Edit of a Cell in `SheetA!A10:A300`

**2.** On the value changes of `SheetB!A1:A5` (which will be changed by formulas like `TODAY`, `NOW` )

Of course it's value will be changed **3 times in a day**

**1** `00:05`  **2** `20:25` **3** `20:49`

So I have setup the **Installable trigger** on my Spreadsheet instead of **onEdit** simple Trigger.

**Code.gs**

```
function ChangeValue() {
  console.log("The Value of the Cell was Changed") ;
}

function onChange(e) {
  range = e.range;
  ss = e.source;
  sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("SCRIPT");
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'SCRIPT!A2') {
    ChangeValue();
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the below error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
```

Comment: you MUST name the function of an on-edit trigger as ```onEdit()```

Comment: @Ping it's not Edit. the value will be changed by it's formula. not by me.

Comment: I just noticed you did mentioned that  ```Cell value will be changed accordingly by it's formula```, that doesn't count as ```change``` or ```edit``` event for apps script, so it won't fires the trigger.

Comment: then how to achieve this bro @Ping ..?

Comment: you need to think of some work around, but it will be difficult for anyone to help you if you are not providing any kind of sample data to work on. At lease we need to know when will the value be changed by what kind of formula.

Comment: @Ping the ```Script!A2``` value is dependent on the Edit of another cells ( ```Syllabus!A10:A300``` ).  If those cells edited. Script!A2 will be changed automatically.

Comment: in that case ... you should check if ```Syllabus!A10:A300``` is edited to fire the trigger, instead of checking ```Script!A2```

Comment: @Ping updated the Question. See ```Script!A2``` value change conditions.

Comment: since you have the error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined```, I'm wording what kind of ```Installable Trigger``` are you using?

Comment: can you share the return with `Logger.log()` of the steps to see what your results are?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

This code check the active sheet, and call the function 'ChangeValue()' only when the sheet name is 'SheetA', edited row is between 10 to 300, and edited column is A.

It works fine as 'onEdit()' trigger or installable onedit trigger in my test cases.

```js
function ChangeValue() {
  console.log("The Value of the Cell was Changed");
}

function onChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const conditions = [
    activeSheet === 'SheetA',
    range.getRow() >= 10,
    range.getRow() <= 300,
    range.getColumn() == 1
  ]
  if (conditions.every(c => c === true)) ChangeValue()
}
```

Comment: This will not solve my problem. Because it's ok with ```condition 1``` but not with ```condition 2``` of the ```Script!A2``` value change. Ofcourse the value was changed ```3 times``` in a day. So can I call ```ChangeValue()``` at these 3 times by Apps Script Editor ..? see Question

Comment: Maybe set a time trigger as installable trigger instead? Juse call the ```ChangeValue()``` function as timer trigger seems to be the way to go?

Comment: Hello @ping I have created another [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74545501/google-apps-script-not-calling-function-on-time-based-condition) for to solve this problem. can you see it ..?