# Google Apps Script not calling function on time based Condition

Tags: javascript, mysql, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Apps Script function named `UpdateDatabase`

And called it by a `if statement`

But the function was being not called when the **condition was met.**

What went wrong or how to call the function on a `Particular time` (Hour & Minutes) ..?

**Code.gs**

```
function UpdateDatabase() {

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SCRIPT");
  data = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue() ;

  server = "give.herosite.pro";
  port = '3306';
  dbName =  "oncjsznl_wp921";
  username = "oncjsznl_wp921";
  password = "xxxxxxxxx";
  url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?characterEncoding=UTF-8";

  conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.execute("UPDATE `my_table` SET `Script`='" + data + "' ;");
  console.log("DB Table Updated successfully")

  conn.close();
}


var now = new Date().getTime() ;

var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var date = d.getDate();
var ctdr = new Date(year, month, date, 16, 10, 00).getTime();

distance = ctdr - now;

if (distance < 0) {
UpdateDatabase() ;
}
```

Comment: It appears you want to check a cell value has changed. You need to use an onEdit() trigger to achieve that

Comment: there are time-driven trigger in apps script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

Comment: @arulselvan I just showed a sample function here for illustration. My actual function is different. It is about updating ```MySQL Database``` I updated the question with actual function. Pls see it.

Comment: @Ping it should be executed at particular time. In time-driven option we have to select either ```hour timer``` or ```minute timer``` but I want both ```hours & minutes```

Comment: You may as well check this answer that could give you an idea on how to handle the scheduling of the function: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/164566/scheduling-a-script-to-run-at-a-specific-time-rather-than-a-range-of-time

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to run the UpdateDabase function every day at 16:10, more or less.

Instead of hardcoding that, you can create a trigger and schedule the time to run any function.

The "Select event source" field must be time-driven in order to set the schedule.

This is the right approach to achieve your purpose.